# Install specific branch of a Lua lib

Tags: lua, dependencies

Luarocks is great and all, but I need to install specific version of a lib, which is not tagged yet.

What's the right way to install a lib, but use the code that's in `master` or of any specific commit.

so for example, when I do: `luarocks install luasocket --local` it would be doing something like:

```
Installing https://luarocks.org/luasocket-3.0rc1-2.src.rock
```

can I force it to fetch the code that's in a specific branch?

Answer (score -1):

You can copy the rockspec file for your module and tweak `source.branch` to point where you need (https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Rockspec-format#build-rules).